# Converting char to short in C

Tags: c, bit-shift

I am considering what the value of ca will be after these operations:

```
int ca = -279;
char abb = ca;
int ca = /abb >> 6) ;
```

I am having trouble understanding what happens with ca because of the shifting.

Comment: Do you want to keep the negative sign i suppose, visualizing -275 as short

Comment: It is implementation-defined, so you may get different results on different implementations. A `char` is guaranteed to represent all values in the range 0 to 127 and is guaranteed to be able to represent all values in one of the ranges -128 to 127 or 0 to 255 (and possibly values outside those ranges) depending on the implementation.

Comment: `char cb` has *already* ovderflowed because it cannot hold the original vlaue `-275`.

Comment: @IanAbbott: If `char` is signed, the C standard does not require it to be able to represent −128 (or if it is unsigned, for that matter). The standard only requires `SCHAR_MIN` be at least −127 in magnitude.

Comment: @WeatherVane: `cb` does not overflow “already” because `char cb = (char) sa;` initializes it with a `char` value (the result of the cast), and the conversion does not overflow; it is implementation-defined.

Comment: @EricPostpischil That's true, if `char` is signed it might not be able to represent -128 in current versions of the standard, although I understand that will change in C23 (because to all intents and purposes there have not been any significant non- 2's complement implementations of C integers).

Comment: @EricPostpischil "`char cb` has *already* overflowed" unless it is an unsigned type where technically there is no overflow.

Comment: @IanAbbott: It could be two’s complement with a trap value, so 10000000 does not represent a value. Although there have not been many of those lately either.

Comment: @EricPostpischil the cast does not prevent overflow. The value overflows whether or not the cast is performed. `-275` is out of range of the typical 8-bit char. The overflow is dealt with.

Comment: I'm relatively blasé about C2X dropping support for signed integer representations other than two's complement, but that will certainly clean up some of these technical details.  It will still be possible for signed integer representations to contain padding bits and have trap representations, but `SCHAR_MIN`'s minimum magnitude will be -128, and `signed char` will not have any trap representations when it is 8 bits wide.

Comment: @JohnBollinger I like the way all the limits have been defined in terms of `_WIDTH` macros in C23 which tells you exactly how many bits you have to play with to avoid trap values.

Comment: By the way, the final working draft of C23 can be downloaded from https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n3054.pdf

Comment: @WeatherVane: There is no overflow. “Overflow” means the **result** of an operation cannot be represented in the destination type. When the implementation defines a result for the cast, that is the result of the operation. For this cast, the defined result fits in the destination type, so there is no overflow. The fact that an operand of the operation cannot be represented in the result type is irrelevant.

Comment: @johnbollinger: in C23, signed char has no padding bits regardless of how many bits it has (6.2.6.2/2), so it can't have a non-value ("trap") representation, even if it is wider than 8 bits.

Comment: Editing question to remove it is seen as vandalizing it. Please don't do that. There are ways to disassociate your account from the question, when it no longer can be deleted, because it has upvoted answers, but I don't really see a reason to do that here.

Answer (score 2):

It appears likely that, in your C implementation, `char` is signed and eight bits. In `(char) sa`, the value of `sa`, −275, cannot be represented in the `char` type. The C standard requires each C implementation to define what it does here, which must be either to produce a value or a trap. It appears your C implementation wraps the value modulo 256, so −275 becomes −275 + 256 = −19.

In `cb << 8`, `cb` is promoted to `int`. In your C implementation, `int` is probably 32 bits, as that is common in implementations that C students use these days. However, left-shifting a negative value is not defined by the C standard. It appears your C implementation produced −4,864, equal to multiplying −19 by 256 or to shifting a two’s complement −19 eight bits to the left.

Then we effectively have `-4864 >> 2`. The C standard says right-shifting a negative value is implementation-defined. It appears your C implementation performed an arithmetic shift. This produced −1,216.

Answer (score 0):

I think short is environment dependent,so you can try this in your environment with printf.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(){

printf("Short Max: %hi \n", SHRT_MAX);
printf("Short Min: %hi \n", SHRT_MIN);

printf("Char Max: %i \n", CHAR_MAX);
printf("Char Min: %i \n", CHAR_MIN);

short sa = -275;
printf("Short: %hi Char: %c\n", sa, sa);

char cb = (char) sa;
printf("Short: %hi Char: %c\n", cb, cb );

short sg = (cb << 8) >> 2;
printf("Short: %hi Char: %c \n", sg, sg);

return 0;

}
```

I get the following:

```
Short Max: 32767 
Short Min: -32768 
Char Max: 127 
Char Min: -128 
Short: -275 Char: �
Short: -19 Char: �
Short: -1216 Char: @
```